# Filter on two many to many relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to apply multiples filter on a table join to two tables

My tables

**main**

- Id
- Name

**tags**

- Id
- Name

**main_primary_tags**

- mainId
- tagId

**main_secondary_tags**

- mainId
- tagId

I want to select some items in **main** table which have some primary and secondary tags.
The difficulity is I need to have an exact result.

Exemple if I want to select items which have "Tag1 and "Tag2" tags, I want to have items which have both of these tags not just one of them (Like IN operator)
And I can filter on primary AND secondary..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I think the design isn't ideal. I would probably just use a single `main_tags` table with a column indicating if it's a main or secondary tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would aggregate the tags into arrays and compare the arrays:

```
select main.id as main_id,
       mt.tags as main_tags,
       st.tags as secondary_tags
from main
  left join lateral (
     select array_agg(mpt.tag order by t.tag) as tags
     from main_primary_tags mpt
       join tags t1 on t1.id = mpt.tagid
     where mpt.mainid = main.id
  ) mt on true
  left join lateral (
     select array_agg(mst.tag order by t.tag) as tags
     from main_secondary_tags mst
       join tags t2 on t2.id = mst.tagid
     where mst.mainid = main.id
  ) st on true
where mt.tags = array['Tag1', 'Tag2']
  and st.tags = array['Tag1', 'Tag2']
```

Note that the `=` operator for arrays depends on the order of the elements, so it's important to list them in the same way `order by` sorts them.

Comment: . . This would not work if there were other primary/secondary tags . . . although it can easily be fixed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: not sure what you mean with "other tags"?

Comment: The OP specifies that the two tags need to be in the result set, but other tags could be.  In addition, it is not clear that they need to both be there as primary and secondary.

Comment: OK, if more than just the two tags are allowed that the condition should be `mt.tags @> ...` indeed

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
WITH tag_filter AS (
    SELECT 'Tag1' AS primary_tag, 'Tag2' AS secondary_tag
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Tag1', 'Tag2'
)
SELECT m.*
FROM "main" m
    INNER JOIN main_primary_tags mpt ON mpt.mainId = m.Id
    INNER JOIN main_secondary_tags mst ON mst.mainId = m.Id
    INNER JOIN tags primary_t ON primary_t.Id = mpt.tagId
    INNER JOIN tags secondary_t ON secondary_t.Id = mst.tagId
    INNER JOIN tag_filter tf
         ON  tf.primary_tag = primary_t."Name"
         AND tf.secondary_tag = secondary_t."Name"
```

Or if you want something more compact in the tag_filter CTE

```
WITH tag_filter AS (
    SELECT primary_tag, secondary_tag
    FROM (VALUES ('Tag1', 'Tag2'), ('Tag1', 'Tag2')) t(primary_tag, secondary_tag)
)
SELECT m.*
FROM "main" m
    INNER JOIN main_primary_tags mpt ON mpt.mainId = m.Id
    INNER JOIN main_secondary_tags mst ON mst.mainId = m.Id
    INNER JOIN tags primary_t ON primary_t.Id = mpt.tagId
    INNER JOIN tags secondary_t ON secondary_t.Id = mst.tagId
    INNER JOIN tag_filter tf
         ON  tf.primary_tag = primary_t."Name"
         AND tf.secondary_tag = secondary_t."Name"
```

And in the case the tag_filter is much smaller than the main table, then you can also spool the tagId in the CTE, and then join with that instead.

```
WITH tag_name_filter AS (
    SELECT primary_tag, secondary_tag
    FROM (VALUES ('Tag1', 'Tag2'), ('Tag1', 'Tag2')) t(primary_tag, secondary_tag)
),
tag_filter AS (
    SELECT primary_t.Id AS primary_tag_id, secondary_t.Id AS secondary_tag_id
    FROM tag_name_filter tmf
        INNER JOIN tags primary_t ON primary_t."Name" = tmf.primary_tag
        INNER JOIN tags secondary_t ON secondary_t."Name" = tmf.secondary_tag
)
SELECT m.*
FROM "main" m
    INNER JOIN main_primary_tags mpt ON mpt.mainId = m.Id
    INNER JOIN main_secondary_tags mst ON mst.mainId = m.Id
    INNER JOIN tag_filter tf
         ON tf.primary_tag_id = mpt.tagId
        AND tf.secondary_tag_id = mst.tagId
```